# Add new values to an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend

I have a project that I am doing with nodejs and react, and created an object but I don't know how to add new values to that object, in such a way that it is like a list, and I tried it this way

Code

```
let = object = {}

object[name] = Value
```

But every time I do console.log of the object if it adds it to me, but when I want to add new values it just modifies that object but doesn't add a new one.

```
{nombreDelObjeto: 'Value'};
```

If anyone knows how to make a .Push type to add new values to the object please help me

Answer (score 1):

```
const myObject = {};

//Add values to object
myObject.name = "John";
myObject.last_name = "Doe"

//Get values from object
myObject.name //"John"
myObject.last_name //"Doe"

//Modify values
myObject.name ="Jane"

console.log(myObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let object = {};
let name = 'new key';

object[name] = 'new value';
console.log(object);
```

Comment: What's with the equal sign after the `let`? I have never seen such a syntax.